# Okhttp return null

Tags: android, okhttp

Why does this code not return anything in Run and return the good result in Debug on activity? TextView return result in Debug.

```
@Data
public class HttpRequest {

    private static String url="url_to_my_server";
    private String answer;
    private OkHttpClient client;

    public HttpRequest() {
        client = new OkHttpClient();
    }

    private void getContent(String method) {
        final Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url+method)
            .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                answer = "Connection is fail";
                System.out.println(answer);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                answer = response.body().string();
                System.out.println("response.body().string()"+answer);
            }
        });
    }

    public String getStringContent(String method) {
        getContent(method);
        return answer;
    }
}

@Data
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String response;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        //code

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        String test = request.getStringContent("test_method");
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: is getContent(..) async or sync ? if async, getStringContent return before network call actually ends. check it putting a breakpoint on methods to see which is returning first

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking "why doesn't my code work?", we ask that you share what research or efforts you've already made, what the desired behavior is and the current behavior of your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Async..How to make the method getContent(..) wait success of getStringContent()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using synchronous request:

```
    public String getStringContent() {
    Request request = new Request.Builder() .url("https://publicobject.com/helloworld.txt") .build(); 
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute())
     { 
   if (!response.isSuccessful()) 
    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response); 
    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) { 
    System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + 
     responseHeaders.value(i)); 
   }
    System.out.println(response.body().string()); 

    return response.body().string();

    }
```

**Update**

```
    @Data
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String response;
    private TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
        //code

        callAsyncMethod();

    }

    public void updateMyUI(String text) {
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(text);

    }

    public void callAsyncMethod(){
           Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            String test = request.getStringContent("test_method");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                 updateMyUI(test)
              }
           });
        }
    };

        thread.start();
    }


}
```

Comment: Yes, it is because you are doing background operation on your main thread. Do you know about Asynctask?

Comment: I updated your activity in my answer , I hope can help you

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of ways to handle background task (handlers, asynctask, loaders , rx , etc)  . Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it works :).